# Why won't my PHP variable appear in the HREF in my CakePHP view?

Tags: php, cakephp

In my CakePHP code I have the following code. If i click on the image delete it moves to the link in href. In the href I dont know how to display my php value. I tried it like below But it didn't work.

```
   <a href="http://localhost/cake_1.2.1.8004/index.php/forms/delete/"<?php echo $r['Form']['id'];?> >
    <img border="0" alt="Delete" src="/cake_1.2.1.8004/app/webroot/img/delete.png"/>
  </a>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your echo in your quotes:

```
<a href="http://localhost/cake_1.2.1.8004/index.php/forms/delete/<?php echo $r['Form']['id'];?>">
    <img border="0" alt="Delete" src="/cake_1.2.1.8004/app/webroot/img/delete.png"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

use cakephp view helpers:

```
<?php
    echo $html->link(
        $html->image('delete.png'),
        array('action'=>'delete', $r['Form']['id']),
        array(),
        'really delete?',
        false
    );
?>
```